# Deploy Azure Databricks workspace in your own Virtual Network (VNet)

Tags: networking, azure-databricks, azure-virtual-network, vnet

I have already provisioned databricks instance, now I need to add Deploy Azure Databricks workspace in your own Virtual Network (VNet) this setting as YES. As I need to make my databricks instance behind Vnet.

How Can I edit it to the already configured instance. Is there any possible way as Networking section is grid out as I selected no previously with Vnet option.

[image]

Comment: Did any one have idea how to again opt for networking in azure databricks. As I already provisioned it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change networking configuration of already deployed workspace. You need to create new one with correct configuration, and then migrate from your existing workspace.

Comment: Thanks Alex that is what we are doing currently.